# I am making a program where you ask use to input three numbers and telling the user if the numbers they entered could be a triangle and what kind

Tags: java, if-statement

I made a program that asks a user to input three numbers and then tells the user if the numbers they entered could make a triangle and what kind of triangle it would be. Each number they enter represents one side of the triangle. I get it to pass all of my test cases except the ones where I enter sides that make the triangle a scalene triangle. The else statement that is supposed to identify the scalene triangles doesn't output and I don't know why.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, my name is Christian");
    System.out.println("In this program you will enter three whole numbers and\nI will tell you if the numbers you entered equal a triange.");
    
    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your first whole number:");
    int sideA = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    
    
    System.out.println("Please enter your second whole number:");
    int sideB = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    
    
    System.out.println("Please enter your third whole number:");
    int sideC = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    
    // This if statement pulls in any combination of integers for evaluation. 
    if (((sideA + sideB) > sideC)||((sideB + sideA) > sideA)||((sideA + sideC) > sideB)){
        
        if (sideA == sideB && sideA == sideC) {
            System.out.println("That is an equilateral triangle.");
        } 
        //this statement identifies any combination of integers that are not triangles.
        if (((sideA + sideB) <= sideC)||((sideB + sideA) <= sideA)||((sideA + sideC) <= sideB)) {
            System.out.println("That is not a valid triangle.");
        }
        
        if (sideA == sideB && (sideA + sideB) > sideC) {
            System.out.println("That is an isosceles triangle.");
        }
        
        if (sideB == sideC && (sideB + sideC) > sideA) {
            System.out.println("That is an isosceles triangle.");
        }
        
        if (sideC == sideA && (sideC + sideA) > sideB) {
            System.out.println("That is an isosceles triangle.");
        
        }


    } else {
        System.out.println("That is a scalene triangle.");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: The condition that leads to the else block is set to pull in any combination of numbers. this is so they can be evaluated by all the other if statements. if they fail the if statements then they are scalene triangles.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

You basically need the following *structure* (pseudo-code):

```
if (is valid) {
    if (is equilateral) {
        print equilateral;
    } else if (is isosceles) {
        print isosceles;
    } else {
        print scalene;
    }
} else {
    print not valid;
}
```

or, slightly changed - as I would prefer, since its *structure* better shows that only ONE output is to be chosen:

```
if (is not valid) {
    print not valid;
} else if (is equilateral) {
    print equilateral;
} else if (is isosceles) {
    print isosceles;
} else {
    print scalene;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first if statement is almost always correct, and it is likely that most of your cases satisfy at least one of the conditions. For instance, "(sideB + sideA) <= sideA" is correct for any two non-negative numbers, so inputting sideA and SideB as any non-negative integers will result in the first if statement being correct and therefore not entering the else statement.

A better approach would be to write it the following way (I use "else if" if you want only one line of output), I also added a check to ensure the integers are positive:

```
    // this statement identifies any combination of integers that are not triangles.
    if (((sideA + sideB) <= sideC) || ((sideB + sideC) <= sideA) || ((sideA + sideC) <= sideB) || sideA <=0 || sideB <=0 || sideC <=0) {
        System.out.println("That is not a valid triangle.");
    }
    // this statement identifies any combination of integers that are equilateral triangles.
    else if (sideA == sideB && sideA == sideC) {
        System.out.println("That is an equilateral triangle.");
    }
    // this statement identifies any combination of integers that are isosceles triangles.
    else if (sideA == sideB || sideB == sideC || sideA == sideC) {
        System.out.println("That is an isosceles triangle.");
    }
    // this catches any scalene triangles.
    else{
        System.out.println("That is a scalene triangle.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no output because your outer if statement is wrong. First of all, you don't need that many brackets - if you remove them, you might find an error, although I'm not sure what you're trying to check for here:

```
if (sideA + sideB > sideC || sideB + sideA > sideA || sideA + sideC > sideB)
```

I think what you meant to write here was (in the second part of the condition) was B + C > A, and also you'd need AND instead of OR between these conditions if you'd like to validate the arguments (thus the inner "this is not a valid triangle" statement would be redundant):

```
if (sideA + sideB > sideC && sideB + sideC > sideA && sideA + sideC > sideB)
```

Then I'd also suggest to use if-else if-else inside it, as in its current state the program evaluates all if statements, despite finding an answer.

The scalene triangle would be the last "else" block, and the outer else block (which now contains the scalene triangle output) would be the "invalid triangle", somehow like this (you can also merge the three isosceles statements into one):

```
if (sideA + sideB > sideC && sideB + sideC > sideA && sideA + sideC > sideB) {
    if (sideA == sideB && sideA == sideC) {
        System.out.println("That is an equilateral triangle.");
    } else if (
      sideA == sideB && (sideA + sideB) > sideC
        || sideB == sideC && (sideB + sideC) > sideA
        || sideC == sideA && (sideC + sideA) > sideB
    ) {
        System.out.println("That is an isosceles triangle.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("That is a scalene triangle.");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("That is not a valid triangle.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.

```
int[][] data = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 2, 8 }, { 8, 8, 8 },
        { 4, 8, 4 }, { 4, 5, 7 }, {7,7,8}, { 5, 3, -2 } };
for (int[] sides : data) {
    System.out.printf("%s : %s%n", Arrays.toString(sides),
            analyze(sides[0], sides[1], sides[2]));
}
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 3] : Is not a valid triangle.
[1, 2, 8] : Is not a valid triangle.
[8, 8, 8] : Is a equilateral triangle.
[4, 8, 4] : Is not a valid triangle.
[4, 5, 7] : Is a scalene triangle.
[7, 7, 8] : Is an isoceles triangle.
[5, 3, -2] : Is not a valid triangle.
```

- first eliminate invalid triangles.
- Invalid triangles are

  - one or more sides <= 0
  - any side >= to the sum of the other two (which captures the first criteria)
- The rest are legal and evaluated by standard tests.  Order is important!

  - first check for equilateral - all sides equal length
  - then for isosceles - two sides equal length
  - default to scalene. - no sides equal length

```
    
public static String analyze(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (a >= b + c || b >= a + c || c >= a + b){
        return "Is not a valid triangle.";
    }

    if (a == b && b == c) {
        return "Is a equilateral triangle.";
    }
    
    if (a == b || b == c || a == c) {
        return "Is an isoceles triangle.";
    }

    return "Is a scalene triangle.";
}
```